# Background-attachment:fixed; not working

Tags: html, css, skrollr

I've searched and searched, but I can't, for the life of me, figure out what is wrong with my background attachment. I can't get it to break free from the div. For brevity, [here is a fiddle for you to observe and test](http://jsfiddle.net/5c9tgj4y/1/). I'm working with Skrollr.js which might be a factor FYI.
The second panel that moves up over the first is the one I'm referring to. And by "break free" I mean that the #panel-2 background is traveling with the #panel-2 div to cover the first panel instead of the #panel-2 background being fixed at the top of the viewport and being "revealed" by the #panel-2 div moving into the viewport.

```
<div id="panel-2" class="panel" data-0="transform:translate3d(0%,100%,0)" data-200p="transform:translate3d(0%,0%,0)"></div>


#panel-2 {
    background: url('http://dev.synergexis.com/skp/example-img/panel-2-bg.jpg') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment:fixed;
    transform:translateZ(0%, 100%, 0);
    -ms-transform:translateZ(0%, 100%, 0);
    /* IE */
    -moz-transform:translateZ(0%, 100%, 0);
    /* Firefox */
    -webkit-transform:translate3d(0%, 100%, 0);
    /* Safari Chrome */
    -o-transform:translateZ(0%, 100%, 0);
    /* Opera */
    z-index:-2;
}
```

[Here is an example of the behavior.](http://dev.synergexis.com/skp/skrollr-demo/) Given by the amazing, I Hate Tomatoes', Petr Tichy... the second section right below the header with the red and blue stars and dots is the effect I would like to mimic.

Comment: I have no idea what you're asking. Which background? What does "break free of the div" mean?

Comment: @sudowned He means that when the user scrolls, he wants the new image to be revealed from the bottom up, so it looks like the old image is being peeled away and replaced with the new one, as opposed to the current look where the new image scrolls on top of it.

Comment: @Shane I can't find anything in the documentation that would make me think this library is capable of what you want. Unless you know of somewhere else that is using this that way, you may need to find another library or write your own code to achieve the effect that you want. If you can provide an example of someone using this library the way you want, that would be a big help.

Comment: @AndrewTet [Given by the amazing, I hate Tomatoes', Petr Tichy](http://dev.synergexis.com/skp/skrollr-demo/)... the second section  right below the header with the red and blue stars and dots. Except I want my div to move while the background stays fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to avoid using css 3dtranslations, the working skrollr demo you are trying to mimic doesn't use them. I have read some complaints about css 3dtranslations ignoring fixing content to viewport before. Once you remove them, the background-attachment should start working.

Comment: Is there another way of doing this so the page still engages hardware acceleration?

Comment: Not sure. Sorry, I have not really engaged this in web development yet. Hopefully someone else will have answer for this.